# PHP query result into variable

Tags: php, mysql, database

Hi everyone I am a beginner programmer trying to get query results into variable in PHP. For registeration purposes, I want to assign an available campaignID to variable $campaignID, so I can insert $campaignID along with other variables to the new user row. **I only need help on getting my result of my SELECT Statement into the variable campaignID!** I am aware that there are multiple questions asking the exact thing want  like [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157905/mysql-query-result-in-php-variable) & [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22521048/assign-mysql-database-value-to-php-variable). However, I have been trying the solutions for hours now but to no avail and I need help to apply the answers to my situation.

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
error_reporting(E_ERROR);
try{
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

    $query = "SELECT campaignID from ebaycampaigns WHERE Taken='N' LIMIT 1";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);

    if(!$result){
        echo "No data was selected";
    }

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result)==1){
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        echo "campaignID: " . $row[0];

        //or
        //$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);
        //printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row['campaignID']);

    }

    else{
        echo "not found!";
    }

    $conn->close();
}
catch(Exception $e) {
    $json_out = "[".json_encode(array("result"=>0))."]";
    echo $json_out;

}

?>
```

None of the responses were echoed, `$row['campaignID']`, `$row[0]`, `$campaignID`. I am also not conerned with SQL injections so far as this is a small project! So feel free to recommend any methods!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off change mysql_fetch_array to mysqli_fetch_array :)

nevermind the following line, iil just leave it in, I saw you used LIMIT.

And secondly change mysqli_num_rows($result)==1 to mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0

Comment: Ok you already solved it haha, the problem was indeed my 'mysql_fetch_array'.  I added a line '$campaignID = $row[0];' to finally assign my result to my variable, $campaignID. Thanks!!! :-) hold on they are saying i need to wait 2min to accept an answer